# How do I allow embedding a youtube video in a asp.net mvc site in my Content Security Policy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-security-policy

In my web.config I have the following:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="Content-Security-Policy" />
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.googleapis.com cdn.raygun.io api.raygun.io; frame-ancestors 'self'" />
```

In my code I'd like to enable embedding youtube videos like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4rp2aLQl7vg?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I'm using https://www.cspisawesome.com/ to assist in setting my Content Security Policy correctly, however, I can't get it right.

I have tried various combinations using frame-src and frame-ancestors.

What should my CSP look like to allow embedding a youtube video?

Thanks.

Comment: I have tried adding the following to my web.config
<remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />

in combination with removing the Content-Security-Policy header

Comment: Using this <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.googleapis.com cdn.raygun.io api.raygun.io; frame-src *.youtube.com" /> gives this error "Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.youtube.com/embed/4rp2aLQl7vg?rel=0 does not permit cross-origin framing."